# Linux folder permissions for multiple users

Tags: linux, permissions

I have the directory /var/app which I've set to be the home directory for the user 'isapp'. The owner of the folder is 'isapp' and the group is 'isapp'. I'm using Amazon's EC2 service, so when you login to SSH you use the user 'ec2-user'. How can I make it so I can access the contents of that directory via SSH? At the moment I get permission denied with and without sudo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can

- Create a group for the users that should be able to access this folder
- Add isapp and ec2-user to this group
- chgrp the /var/app folder to this group
- chmod the /var/app folder and allow read and execute access for the group `chmod g+rx /var/app`

The fact that you cannot access this folder with sudo is more strange, `sudo cd /var/app` is not expected to work but `sudo ls /var/app` should.

Comment: Thanks. It is actually just cd which doesn't work, ls worked fine. I followed your instructions but unfortunately I still get permission denied.. grep shows isapp:x:503:isapp,ec2-user. I'll keep playing :)

Comment: I edited my instructions and added a 4th one, does it solve it?

Comment: Added that on but the same problem exists! Both users are definitely in the group and the group name on the app directory is the group. When you said chown I presume you meant chgrp.

Comment: you confirm you relogged with these users after having changed their groups? If yes maybe you need to `chmod a+rx /var` since its the parent of this folder.

Comment: Aha! Didn't realise you had to relogin.. that's done the trick! I presumed it would just update the permissions & groups in realtime. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

usermod -G ec2-user isapp

chmod g+rwx /var/app